# How to change channel admin privileges after promoting?

Tags: telegram

I have promoted a channel member to admin. How to edit his privileges ***AFTER*** promoting?

PS: I know you can set privileges ***when*** promoting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh. Figured it out. Manage Channel -> Admins.